# How to exclude specific rule in a custom phpcs.xml ruleset?

Tags: coding-style, phpcs

I am looking for a way to automate coding standards and I've decided to use `SlevomatCodingStandard.TypeHints.TypeHintDeclaration` in our phpcs.xml file. Unfortunately we have faced with an issue with the error reporting:

`38 | ERROR | [ ] @var annotation of property
     |       |     \VC4A\ConvertUploadsToS3::$missing_local_files
     |       |     does not specify type hint for its items.
  45 | ERROR | [ ] @var annotation of property
     |       |     \VC4A\ConvertUploadsToS3::$missing_s3_files does
     |       |     not specify type hint for its items.
  52 | ERROR | [ ] @var annotation of property
     |       |     \VC4A\ConvertUploadsToS3::$updated_s3_links does
     |       |     not specify type hint for its items.
  66 | ERROR | [ ] @var annotation of property
     |       |     \VC4A\ConvertUploadsToS3::$s3_settings does not
     |       |     specify type hint for its items.
 112 | ERROR | [ ] Method \VC4A\ConvertUploadsToS3::setup_crons()
     |       |     does not have return type hint nor @return
     |       |     annotation for its return value.
 149 | ERROR | [ ] @return annotation of method
     |       |     \VC4A\ConvertUploadsToS3::get_cron_actions() does
     |       |     not specify type hint for items of its traversable
     |       |     return value.
 202 | ERROR | [ ] @return annotation of method
     |       |     \VC4A\ConvertUploadsToS3::get_cron_intervals()
     |       |     does not specify type hint for items of its
     |       |     traversable return value.
 266 | ERROR | [ ] @param annotation of method
     |       |     \VC4A\ConvertUploadsToS3::error_reporting() does
     |       |     not specify type hint for items of its traversable
     |       |     parameter $uploads.
 334 | ERROR | [ ] @param annotation of method
     |       |     \VC4A\ConvertUploadsToS3::update_s3_link() does
     |       |     not specify type hint for items of its traversable
     |       |     parameter $upload.
 336 | ERROR | [x] Method \VC4A\ConvertUploadsToS3::update_s3_link()
     |       |     does not have void return type hint.`

I want to add strict return types for methods only but for the DocBlocks we are using `WordPress-Docs` standards.

Is there a way to disable the rest of the errors except the last one ?

What I've tried was this:

`<rule ref="SlevomatCodingStandard.TypeHints.TypeHintDeclaration">
        <exclude name="SlevomatCodingStandard.TypeHints.TypeHintDeclaration.MissingParameterTypeHint"/>
        <exclude name="SlevomatCodingStandard.TypeHints.TypeHintDeclaration.enableEachParameterAndReturnInspection"/>
        <exclude name="SlevomatCodingStandard.TypeHints.TypeHintDeclaration.normalizedTraversableTypeHints"/>
        <exclude name="SlevomatCodingStandard.TypeHints.TypeHintDeclaration.normalizedUsefulAnnotations"/>
    </rule>`

Apparently this does not have any effect. Any suggestions ? Or what could be the proper way to add that specific rule only ?

Or is it possible to do it other way around ? Just add a specific rule in a ruleset without modifying the codebase ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently, I should have used the constant values instead of class data member names:

`<!-- Strict type return for methods -->
    <rule ref="SlevomatCodingStandard.TypeHints.TypeHintDeclaration">
        <exclude name="SlevomatCodingStandard.TypeHints.TypeHintDeclaration.MissingTraversableParameterTypeHintSpecification"/>
        <exclude name="SlevomatCodingStandard.TypeHints.TypeHintDeclaration.MissingTraversablePropertyTypeHintSpecification"/>
        <exclude name="SlevomatCodingStandard.TypeHints.TypeHintDeclaration.MissingTraversableReturnTypeHintSpecification"/>
    </rule>`

Source: 
https://github.com/slevomat/coding-standard/issues/570#issuecomment-448647567